# Couchbase document id generation

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have an Springboot application integrated with couchbase 6.0.
I have read that if a key is annotated with @Id then it will saved as an document id and will not be a part of the json.

Then i have used @Id and @Field together on the key but still that field is not appearing on json document.

Can somebody help me out on the following:

1: How to make same key as document id and keep that a part of json also.

2: If a field is declared with @Id, it is created as document id and  does 
   not appear on document, but when i do a get request same key appear on 
   the response.

I have also tried, click here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.autokeygeneration.usingattributes

My entity is:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.USE_ATTRIBUTES,delimiter="::")
private String id;
@IdAttribute
private String userid;
@Field
private String fname;
@Field
private String lname;
```

Post method body:

{

```
"id": "888",
"userid":"user1",
"fname": "xyz",
"lname": "abc"
```

}

In Couchbase server, it is saving this document as

[image]

It is creating document id as **888** only, it is supposed to generate documnet id as **888::user1**

I have tested this many times but the result is same.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the answer, please take a look

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're looking for [Key generation using attributes:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.autokeygeneration.usingattributes)

> It is a common practice to generate keys using a combination of the
>   document attributes. Key generation using attributes concatenates all
>   the attribute values annotated with IdAttribute, based on the ordering
>   provided similar to prefixes and suffixes.

So, for example you can do:

```
@Document
public class User {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = USE_ATTRIBUTES)
  private String id;
  @IdAttribute
  private String userid;
  ...
}
```

According to the example above you will get as a result a Document with the `id = userId` and also the field `userId` in the json.

**UPDATE AS PER QUESTION EDIT**

You may have to include a new filed in your entity, let's say `postId` and change the naming of the `id` field in your post method body by `postId`, something like:

Entity:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.USE_ATTRIBUTES,delimiter="::")
private String id;
@IdAttribute(order = 0)
private String postId;
@IdAttribute(order = 1)
private String userid;
@Field
private String fname;
@Field
private String lname;
```

Post method body:

```
{
"postId": "888",
"userid":"user1",
"fname": "xyz",
"lname": "abc"
}
```

Comment: @julumn, could you please check my edited post above. I have tested as per your solution but it didn't work.

Comment: @lokendralovely please take a look to the updated answer